# Countable set if the cardinal number is smaller than aleph null

Tags: real-analysis, first-countable

I have a question about countability od a set. I am confused with this problem, it seems like it holds but i am not sure.

If a set $A$ has cardinal number smaller than the cardinal number of the set of all natural numbers, does it imply that $A$ is countable?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, that is the standard terminology: a countable set is one that is finite or countably infinite. Some people do use *countable* to mean *countably infinite*, but this is not the normal usage.

Comment: Yes it is clear to me now, thank you. Can You help me with this equivalentproblem to the previous? If a set has cardinal number bigger than the cardinal number of the set of all natural numbers, does it imply that the set is uncountable? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes: an uncountable set is one whose cardinality is greater than that of $\Bbb N$.